# apache2 is not active

Tags: apache2

What is the error? please give me full solutions!Thank you)

```
sudo service apache2 status

 apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Бс 2018-04-05 16:53:39 +06; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5334 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5317 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir apache2[5317]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir apache2[5317]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir apache2[5317]: Action 'start' failed.
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir apache2[5317]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir apache2[5334]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir apache2[5334]:  *
Сәу 05 16:53:39 moldir systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete answer (it is too long to post as a comment though), as the error you are getting is a segmentation fault and it is hard to figure out the issue without more info.

However, all the times I used to get this problem ended up being due to some conflicting modules.

You can check which modules are enabled on Apache by running the following command:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

However, it is more than likely that this command will actually break and give you the following output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action '-M' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

If that was the case, you will need to use the following command:

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

Make sure there aren't mods that would conflict with each other, for example `php5.6` and `php7.0`, or `mpm_event` and `mpm_prefork`.

To disable them, use the `a2dismod <module_name>` command. For example:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
```